# Do I need to send one sample email to google before sending schema marked up email?

Tags: google-schemas

I was trying my hands on Gmail Schema Marked up email.

Thus I want to clarify few things that do I need to register, submit and send one sample marked up email(gmail-schema-whitelisting-samples@google.com) to google before sending the email to my customers.

Answer (score 2):

Email senders that want to use Actions in the Inbox need to be whitelisted, as documented at https://developers.google.com/gmail/actions/registering-with-google. That involves filling the registration form with the details of the use case, and sending a sample email with markup to that address.